# Python: change "\" to "\\"

Tags: python, replace

I have an entry field that allows the user to enter their own directory/path structure when saving a file, if the user just copies their directory from windows explorer you can get text like "c:\directory\file.ext"  how can I take text entered like that and replace it with the necessary "\" for the os module to use?

Comment: It's just a string, so standard string operations: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html find backslash, replace with two backslashes.

Comment: Most likely, you can just use the string you read from user input directly. You do not need to double the backslashes; that's only for string literals in source code.

Comment: Please show us your code. What have you tried and how it is not working.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to add extra backslashes? Post your code please.

Answer (score 1):

Use a raw string to get the backslashes

```
>>> path = r"c:\test\123"
>>> path
'c:\\test\\123'
>>> print path
c:\test\123
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `os.path.normpath()` would be helpful to you - and the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)